# Get active rows between from and to date range inclusive of boundary

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Table `testTable` has 4 columns

- `sessionid int`
- `started datetime`
- `ended datetime`
- `SessionIsRunning bool` - will be true if last session has not yet ended. Max only one record can be true at anytime since at the most only one session can be running. If no session is running then all records have this as false.

Given two dates say `fromDate` and `toDate`, how do I get the first session that started on or after `fromDate` and the last session that ended on or before `toDate`. Tricky condition is that if a session is in progress and it's `start date >= fromDate` we need this. I am guessing it might not be possible to get both the min and max session id in one sql statement and keep the code readable and easy to maintain. Two separate sql statements is ok. one to get min and one to get max. Then I can query rows using between min and max.

**This last statement explains it in a different way. Get all sessions that started or was running and ended or was running between from/to dates thank you**

Comment: TSQL is for Sybase or SQL Server -- not MySQL.  Which is it?

Comment: Would be willing to bet its mySql, since getting your db wrong is less likely than getting its flavor of sql wrong.

Comment: It took me a while to figure the dateadd stuff. For others who are wondering here is a nice link on this http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considering your edits and the comments regarding BETWEEN, this should give you the result set you need. It will pull any record where SessionIsRunning = true as well as sessions thats started AND ended in the date range.

```
SELECT * FROM testTable tt
WHERE (tt.started >= fromDate AND tt.started < DATEADD(DAY, 1, toDate)
   AND tt.ended >= fromDate AND tt.ended < DATEADD(DAY, 1, toDate))
   OR SessionIsRunning = true
ORDER BY tt.sessionid
```

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive.  You just have to worry about the end date being at 0:00:00 if you don't specify a time.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that for me mootinator.

Comment: If they are full dates with no time, better to avoid between altogether and use an open-ended range. Instead of BETWEEN start AND end, better to say >= BETWEEN AND < DATEADD(DAY, 1, end).

Comment: gets the correct min session but max session is one short (when no session is live or running)

Comment: Try it now. I added the DATEADD(...) part.

Comment: If fromdate is between a running session it is not picked up (min session). ie., the session started before fromdate and ended after fromdate but <= todate.

Comment: Justin, I have updated my question to make it more clear. It was quite confusing to word the question but I think I finally have it clear now. thanks

Comment: Still the boundary problem. A Session that started before fromdate but ended after fromdate  is not picked up. (the first session query from the 2 queries you have posted above.) thanks

Comment: I've updated the query again to take into consideration the issue with BETWEEN as well as to add a missing parenthesis. This query should work as you've requested.

Comment: If a session started before todate and ended after todate (the other boundary condition) I am not sure will be handled. I will play with this further. However I now see that it is a matter of juggling with and/or's and handling all the cases. So I am going to select your query as the answer. After testing I will post final solution for others who maybe interested. thanks Justin.

Answer (score 1):

Getting only the first and last value in a single query (because your question made me curious how to actually write this, even though that doesn't appear to be what you're really asking):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ATable ORDER BY AColumn ASC) first
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ATable ORDER BY AColumn DESC) last
```